# looping an if statement in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

hey i have an if and else statement that i would like to loop if the else occurs as this means that the user hasn't entered the required amount so the program restarts here is the code any ideas?

```
System.out.println("The area of the glass is " + area );

    if (thick == 3)
    {

        System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price1);
        System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final1  );
    }
    else if (thick == 5)
    {

        System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price2);
        System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final2);
    }

    else if (thick == 7)
    {

    System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price3);
    System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final3);
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Sorry for the inconvenience but we do not do this size thinkness.");    //If the we don't have the thickness this is displayed 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean you are checking for user input and if they enter it incorrectly you want to start over?

Comment: yeah basically if the user does not enter 3 5 or 7 then i want the program to restart pretty new to java so any examples would be a big help

Comment: just added another answer, you should have a few suggestions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a while loop that loops until the variable is acceptable:

```
thick = 0;
while (thick != 3 && thick != 5 && thick != 7) {
    // read new thick value from user
    // your current code
}
```

You could express the above more neatly as follows:

```
for (thick = 0; !Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7).contains(thick);)
    // read new thick value from user
    // your current code
}
```

Comment: Thank you alls i needed was plain and simple for a assignment task cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop. If a valid response is entered, break out of the loop. Otherwise, keep looping.

Example:

```
while(true){
    <get input here>
    if(thick==3){
        <do stuff>
        break;
    }
    else if(...){
        <do stuff>
        break;
    }
    ...
    else{
        <do stuff>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
your code 
}while(the_else_occurs);
```

Namely:

```
boolean flag=false;
do{
    if (thick == 3)
    {

        System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price1);
        System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final1  );
    }
    else if (thick == 5)
    {

        System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price2);
        System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final2);
    }

    else if (thick == 7)
    {

    System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price3);
    System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final3);
    }
    else {
        flag=true;
    System.out.println("Sorry for the inconvenience but we do not do this size thinkness.");    //If the we don't have the thickness this is displayed
    }
    }while(flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should throw in some input validation:

```
while(thick != 3 && thick != 5 && thick != 7 && thick != null){

    System.out.println("Sorry for the inconvenience but we do not do this size thinkness.");    

    //If the we don't have the thickness this is displayed 
}
```

Comment: thanks @rink.attendant.6 should have let me fix it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try creating a method and recalling it (recursion) if its not entered correctly:

```
public void MyMethod() {

System.out.println("The area of the glass is " + area );

if (thick == 3)
{

    System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price1);
    System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final1  );
}
else if (thick == 5)
{

    System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price2);
    System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final2);
}

else if (thick == 7)
{

System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + price3);
System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + Final3);
}
else
{
System.out.println("Sorry for the inconvenience but we do not do this size thinkness.");    //If the we don't have the thickness this is displayed 
MyMethod();
}
}
```

The only thing with this is that you have to be careful of overflowing your stack. A `switch` statement might be a good idea to substitute though. Just a few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hash map instead:

```
HashMap<int, PointF> map = new HashMap<int, PointF>()
{
    { 3, new PointF(4.5f, 6) },
    { 5, new PointF(8, 6.3f) },
    { 6, new PointF(9, 8) },
};

if (map.containsKey(thick))
{
   System.out.println("The price to replace the glass will be £" + map.get(thick).x);
   System.out.println("With VAT the price is £" + map.get(thick).y);
}
```

if you can switch PointF with your custom class it woulb be WAY better